# How to get text on canvas using onTouch event in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am implementing pagecurl effect using canvas in android now i have to implement text to speech functionality on same canvas..So two different functionalities on single ontouch event ..Upto now i implemented pagecurl effect onTouch now i am in confusion to get text on canvas..
i used

```
 canvas.drawText("Hello world this is experiment", 300,400 , paint);
```

in my app the text will come dynamically from sqlite..Is there any way to detect text on canvas on touch.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/12549951/760489