# How to Measure TextView Height Based on Device Width and Font Size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-view, textview

I am looking for method in Android that will take a input (text, text_font_size, device_width) and based on these calculations it will return how much height will required to display particular text ?

I am setting a text view/ webview height runtime based on his content,I am aware about warp content but I can't use in my case because of some web view minimum height issue.

So I am trying to calculate height and based on that I am setting view height.

I have tried with following ways

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(text.length()); 
Rect bounds = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, 1, bounds);
mTextViewHeight= bounds.height();
```

So output is

1) "Hello World" returns a height of 13 for font 15

2) "The latest version of Jelly Bean is here, with performance optimizations" returns a height 16 for font 15

Then I have tried with

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(15);
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

Rect bounds = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), result);

Paint.FontMetrics metrics = brush.getFontMetrics();
int totalHeight = (int) (metrics.descent - metrics.ascent + metrics.leading);
```

So output is

1) "Hello World" returns a height of 17 for font 15

2) "The latest version of Jelly Bean is here, with performance optimisations" returns a height of 17 for font 15

if I set these values to my view then its cutting some text, its not showing all content.

Again it looks OK on some tables as its having big width but not on phone.

Is there any way to calculate height based on content ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
public static int getHeight(Context context, String text, int textSize, int deviceWidth) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
    int widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(deviceWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    int heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    textView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    return textView.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

If `textSize` is not given in pixels, change the first paramter of `setTextSize()`.

Comment: what is text size basically ?

Answer (score 11):

I've got a easier method to know the real height of a line before be painted, I don't know if this help you guys, but my solution to get the height of a line it's independent of the height of the layout, just take the font metrics like this:

```
myTextView.getPaint().getFontMetrics().bottom - myTextView.getPaint().getFontMetrics().top)
```

with that we get the real height that the fonts will take from the textview to be painted. This not give you an int, but you can make a Math.round to get a near value.

Comment: that best answer

`final int newHeight = myTextView.getLineCount() * (int) (myTextView.getPaint().getFontMetrics().bottom - myTextView.getPaint().getFontMetrics().top);`

Comment: Great answer. Note: You can also get an int directly with `myTextView.getPaint().getFontMetricsInt()`

Answer (score 9):

`Paint.getTextBounds()` returns not what you would expect. Details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7579469/1048087).

Instead, you can try this way:

```
int mMeasuredHeight = (new StaticLayout(mMeasuredText, mPaint, targetWidth, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, true)).getHeight();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what should be used to reassemble native TextView height when drawing text.

Comment: What about a custom font?

Comment: you can add the custom font to the mPaint