# Android how to fit the textsize in textview

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="3" 
                android:weightSum="4">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="P" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="Bryant" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="27" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

When the outest layout's height is 120dp, the text can not be shown the whole word(e.g. 'y' only shwo upper part), I think it is because the textsize is too big.
However, when I set to 150dp, the text can be shown whole word.
Is any method to set the textsize of the text auto fit the textview to show the whole word.
I don't want to hard-code the textsize to 12sp.
And also, I want to do only in xml.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought of setting your LinearLayout to `wrap_content` instead of 120dp?

Comment: or setting your text view height to `wrap_content`

Comment: I just couldn't see any reason why it's not showing whole text... Would you mind to post the whole xml ? Because as much as i can see, you just ratio your texts height so they should be seen. And 120dp is enough for 4 text with default textsize i assume...

Comment: Ahhaa... in your linearlayout, you set layout_width, layout_height and also layout_weight... You shouldn't do that... I just don't know which part of your layout should get weight as 3, but you should set it to 0 (width or height)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you, there is no easy way to auto-size the font for the TextView.  I would suggest making the TextView's wrap_content for height, instead of a static height.

If you find that there's not enough room on the screen, maybe wrap the entire thing in a ScrollView?

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="120dp">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="P" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Bryant" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="27" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to automatically change the font size to adjust text to fit a certain size.

Answer (score 0):

Not only there is no auto fit for text, but the implementation is also [not trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549182/android-paint-measuretext-vs-gettextbounds).

I'd recommend another UI approach altogether. This is going to bring you headache after headache.