# How to know what size a TextView WOULD be with certain string

Tags: android, textview

Maybe I'm not entering the right keywords, but I'm not finding an answer. I want to know what the dimensions of a TextView would be if I were set it with a certain string. However, I want to know before everything gets laid out in the activity.

My TextView has a fixed width and a variable height. I can get the height like this:

```
myTextView.setText(myString);

// ... UI gets laid out ...

myTextView.getHeight()
```

I want to change the width of the TextView if the height gets past a certain point. (But not before then.) And rather than waiting until after the UI gets laid out, I want to know beforehand what the height would be if it had myString and then change the width if I needed to.

I looked at the [Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html) class but I couldn't figure out what to do. I wonder if it might have something to do with overriding the TextView's onMeasure but I really don't know how to attempt that. Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

Thanks to both @user3249477 and @0xDEADC0DE for their answers. I'm marking @user3249477's answer as the solution for now (although since I need multiple resizes of the view I'm not sure about repeatedly turning the visibility on and off) but also +1 to @0xDEADC0DE for giving me the keywords I needed to further look into this problem.

I need to do more research and testing on this. Here are some links that I have found helpful so far:

OnLayoutChangeListener:

- [View.OnLayoutChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener.html)
- [Capture Layout resize before API 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397959/capture-layout-resize-before-api-11)
- [After changing a property on a LayoutParams object, do I need to call setLayoutParams again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398159/after-changing-a-property-on-a-layoutparams-object-do-i-need-to-call-setlayoutp)

measureText() and getTextBounds():

- [Android Paint: .measureText() vs .getTextBounds()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549182/android-paint-measuretext-vs-gettextbounds)
- [Paint.getTextBounds() returns to big height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425306/paint-gettextbounds-returns-to-big-height)
- [Gettextbounds in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714600/gettextbounds-in-android/14766372#14766372)

Overriding onSizeChanged of the parent view also looks intriguing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14399163/3681880

Comment: I would now use a `StaticLayout` to approach this problem. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41779935/3681880).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `TextView` to invisible:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

and measure it. Once you're done set it to visible:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
final int maxHeight = 500;
myTextView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                               int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        v.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        Log.e("TAG", "H: " + v.getHeight() + " W: " + v.getWidth());

        if (v.getWidth() > maxHeight) {
            params.width += 100;
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it without overriding. If you get the `TextView`s `Paint` with `getPaint()`, you can use `measureText(string)` the get the minimal with of the `TextView` when it is drawn with that `Paint`. I looks like this:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
float textWidth = textView.getPaint().measureText("Some Text");
```

**Update**
To get the height, you can call `getTextBounds()` on the `Paint` object like this:

```
    String text = "Some Text";
    Rect textBounds = new Rect();
    textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);
    float height = textBounds.height();
    float width = textBounds.width();
```

Comment: This returns the text width, while OP asked for the height of the TextView.

Comment: The problem with your update is, that it crams all the text into a single line. So height is only the height of the font.