# Measure text returns float value

Tags: android

It is a stupid question, probably...
However, what is the unit of measure of the `measureText()` value returned?
I need the width of a text in px.
I thought px, dp, sp would be integer values. So why `measureText()` in `TextPaint` returns a float value?

Comment: `measureText()` returns the width of the text. width is a float value

Comment: And what does it represent? pixels?

Answer (score 1):

Why would the return type not be a `float`, representhing pixels?

Drawing on screen uses `float`s all the way down to the GPU level. This makes calculations more convenient and makes it possible to use antialiasing and [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering).

Dimensions such as px, dp, sp [are floats too](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimension%28int%29), though there are [convenience methods to get an integer pixel size value](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelSize%28int%29).

Comment: Ok thanks. But what does the returned value represent? Pixels?

Answer (score -1):

as per the documentation.........

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.String)
[image]

Comment: This just repeats waht is stated in the question: a float is returned. It does not answer the "why" question.

Answer (score -1):

The returned value is the number of pixels (not dp or sp), thus is returned as you need it :) It is returned as a float probably due to the official Android classes finding a float value more useful for calculations and optimization, but I could be wrong on that.

Comment: I don't think it is in px... I've written an algorithm in which it compares the width of the text with the width if the textView (myTextView.getWidth()). And looking at the result I'm pretty sure that value is not in px :(

Comment: How far out are the two values? Does this link following help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549182/android-paint-measuretext-vs-gettextbounds