# Android TextView Display HTML With DL DT tags

Tags: android, html, textview

Is there anyway to display DL DT and DD tags inside a TextView?  I tried this

```
rawString is an array of "<dt>Some Name</dt><dd>Some text</dd>"

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("<dl>");
for (String s : rawString) {
    builder.append(s);
}
builder.append("</dl>");
```

But this doesn't seem to be interpreted even if I use Html.fromHtml() when i set the text

```
setText(Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));
```

I guess if this will never work then is there a way to display information like this in a single textview where we have a 2 column or 3 column data and to line up the columns?

```
Name:    The name
tim:     value
yells:   yes
```

If I use Webview then the data looks like this:

```
Name:
         The name
tim:
         value
yells:
         yes
```

Seems like there is no way to display this without using a listview

Answer (score 0):

`Html.fromHtml()` handles a limited set of HTML tags. [This blog post of mine from 2010](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) lists the then-current set, and I am not aware that it has changed much. Quickly eyeballing [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java) does not indicate any obvious changes.

So, you have a few choices, off the top of my ever-so-balding head:

1. Do something other than those tags.
2. Add a `TagHandler` to your `fromHtml()` call and figure out how to set up spans that will format things the way you want.
3. Use a `WebView`.

> I guess another question would if this will never work then is there a way to display information like this in a single textview:

Getting them aligned like that will be difficult without a monospace font. You might be able to go through [some text-measurement stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549182/android-paint-measuretext-vs-gettextbounds) to try to determine the right amount of whitespace to add to get things to align, or invent some spans to fill the space. It's one of those things that strikes me as being painful but eventually doable.

Comment: Webview is horrible it has so many bugs and way too much for what I need here.  Be better off using div tags instead.

Comment: @JPM: Bear in mind that `<div>` does not accept attributes, insofar as `fromHtml()` is concerned. It's treated just as a paragraph delimiter.

Comment: Ugh thanks for saving me time with divs...I'll try webview (in a dejected voice)

Comment: Webview displays the data incorrectly too.  Looks like I'll have to use ListView with custom Adapter instead.

Comment: @CommonsWare why is it almost every time you answer a question you never upvote it?  You took the time to answer someones question so why not upvote?  You have a huge reputation, why not spread the wealth?  Almost all of your new answers(the last 10 or so) have questions that are still 0.