# How do we set a custom line height in a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, baseline, fontmetrics, line-height

I am working on a custom `TextView` where we are highlighting certain words in the `String` with a green background drawable. The drawable is dependent on the line height for the word it is highlighting and will draw itself according to the top and bottom of the particular line it is on, as shown below:

[image]

Now, if we zoom into the word that is highlighted, you can see that I've drawn the baseline in red, the top line in blue, and the bottom line in yellow. Per design, the top line (blue) should be 14px from the baseline and the bottom line (yellow) should be 8px from the baseline. The total line height, therefore, is 22px.

[image]

The green drawable will automatically extend its top to the top of the line (blue) and its bottom to the bottom of the line (yellow).

The problem is, when I try to set the `lineHeight` attribute in XML or programmatically, it doesn't get set correctly and you can see that here:

[image]

The `lineHeight` is 22px, but you can see that the line's top and bottom edges aren't positioned correctly. I need the `TextView` to correctly position the top of each line to the blue line and the bottom of each line to the yellow line.

My question is: Is there anywhere to specify the `lineHeight` or modify the `TextView` so that it appears exactly like the design, as shown in the first two screenshots?

The desired result is that the top of the line should be about 14px from the baseline and the bottom of the line should be about 8px from the baseline, totaling a 22px line height.

Can we do this manually in Android and if so, how?

These are some of the resources I've been working through:

1. https://suragch.medium.com/meaning-of-top-ascent-baseline-descent-bottom-and-leading-in-androids-fontmetrics-c80cf019aef5
2. [Meaning of top, ascent, baseline, descent, bottom, and leading in Android's FontMetrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631736/meaning-of-top-ascent-baseline-descent-bottom-and-leading-in-androids-font)
3. https://developpaper.com/how-to-use-android-text-baseline-algorithm/
4. [Truly top-aligning text in Android TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680079/truly-top-aligning-text-in-android-textview)

...but they aren't exactly what I need.

Comment: I will be interested to see if anyone has a solution for you. It seems to me that you are constrained by the metrics of the font, specifically the relative values of descent to ascent which I don't believe you can change. You don't specify a font but, maybe you can identify a font with the right metrics. You can also consider making your own font with the metrics you desire  if you or your designer have the expertise.

Comment: Could you try adding these 3 attributes to the textView? `android:firstBaselineToTopHeight="22dp" android:lastBaselineToBottomHeight="8dp" android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"`