# Paint.measureText: Is the sum of the parts equal to the whole?

Tags: android, string, paint, measure

If I have a string like this

```
String myString = "This is some text.";
```

Will I get the same lengths if I measure the entire string as when I take the sum of measuring each character?

At first thought, I assumed the answer to be yes, but then I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7579469/3681880), which  said `measureText` adds an `AdvanceX` value before *and* after each measurement. If that is true, then it would add a subtle error into measuring summed lengths (because there would be double padding between each character).

I also know that there is [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) with some fonts that changes how close letters are placed together depending on the surrounding text. This is making me think more and more that a sum of the parts will be different than the whole.

[image: kerning]

The image comes from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning).

This is important because I am making my own custom text view that needs to handle line wrapping. If a single word is too long for the line then I measure each character until I discover where I need to break. However, I assumed that summing the measure of the individual character widths would be the same as measuring the whole string.

I have set up this question so that I can answer it below after I am finished with my tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole is **not** always equal to the sum of the parts.

This appears to be a result of kerning and not related to any AdvanceX double padding that you mentioned.

**Test code**

Here is the test code:

```
String myString = "This is some text.";

Paint myPaint = new Paint();
myPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
myPaint.setTextSize(100);

float theWhole = myPaint.measureText(myString);

float sumOfTheParts = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
    sumOfTheParts += myPaint.measureText(myString, i, i + 1);
}
```

**Results**

In my first test, the measures are the same:

```
String myString = "This is some text.";

theWhole        // 787.0
sumOfTheParts   // 787.0
```

However, when there are letters that need kerning, the measures are different. This is the test again with a different string:

```
String myString = "AV Wa";

theWhole        // 291.0
sumOfTheParts   // 297.0
```

**Implications**

You cannot assume that measuring all the characters of a string and then summing the total will give you the actual length of the string. Thus, when doing text wrapping you will need to measure entire string ranges.