# Set width of TextInputEditText to n characters

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I'm trying to implement a layout where user will input their phone number. The phone number will be 11 digits. And so I wanted to build a text input field with a fixed width that can accommodate 11 characters.

NOTE: I don't want the input field to be wider than 11 characters. Let's say each character is 10px wide. So the input field should be 11*10px = 110px wide (I'm not taking the drawable icon into account here).

Here's what I've tried in XML:

```xml
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textField"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_48"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_phone">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/phone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="11"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="11"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minEms="11"
                    android:text="01"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:typeface="monospace" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

But this produces an output like the following:

[image: Screenshot of UI]

As you can see, despite using `ems` and `minEms`, the field is 2 characters wide (it's 0 character wide if I don't add `android:text`). But I want it to have a width of 11 characters (not more or less). Why is `ems` not effective here and what's the solution?

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content" set this to match parent

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa sorry for the ambiguity, but I wanted to create an input field such that it it neither wider than nor smaller than 11 characters. After using the match parent, the TextInputEditText became wider than 11 characters.

Comment: Your own approach should work then. What about the parent view of 'TextInputLayout'. I think the problem is there.

Comment: I think you're underestimating the difficulty of this. The TextView doesn't _necessarily_ know the effective measured size of a single glyph/character. Text measuring is an expensive computation and would greatly vary between fonts, styles, densities, etc. You'd have to [measure the text on a canvas like Android does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549182/android-paint-measuretext-vs-gettextbounds) and then convert `px` to `dp` and resize your TextView accordingly.

Comment: You can achieve it using ConstraintLayout. Add one more TextInputEditText outside the TextInputLayout and make it invisible. and align TextInputLayout on top of it.

Comment: what you can do add a text view and on its foreground put edittext with width starting from that views start to end it will automatically fill up space

Answer (score 2):

For me the given answers didn't work. But this did:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
  ...
  android:maxEms="12"
  minEms="12">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    ...
    singleLine="true">
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just edit your layout width

*from*

```
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

*to*

```
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

**I just edited your code**

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
       

         android:id="@+id/textField"
                    
            
            
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_48"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_phone">
    
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/phone"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="11"
                        android:inputType="phone"
                        android:maxLength="11"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:minEms="11"
                        android:text="01"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:typeface="monospace" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: pardon the ambiguity, but I actually wanted an input field which will not be larger, nor smaller than the total width of 11 characters. Because of using match parent, the field becomes wider than 11 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You should set a 11 digits monospace text in your `TextInputEditText` widget (for example `12345678901`), then define a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` in your fragment, that calculates the width when the layout is available to be measured.

You could instantiate the observer in `onResume()` of your fragment, and remove it in `onPause()`. You should also store the width during the rotation of the activity.

Here below a full working example:

*MainActivity.java*:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    TextInputEditText textInputEditText;
    int viewWidth;

    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener viewTreeObserver = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                constraintLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                constraintLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
            viewWidth = textInputEditText.getMeasuredWidth();
            textInputEditText.setWidth(viewWidth);
            textInputEditText.setText("");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            viewWidth = savedInstanceState.getInt("viewWidth", 0);
        }

        constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.id_constraintlayout);
        textInputEditText = findViewById(R.id.phone);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("viewWidth", viewWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (viewWidth == 0) {
            textInputEditText.setText("12345678901");
            ViewTreeObserver vto = constraintLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(viewTreeObserver);
        } else textInputEditText.setWidth(viewWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            constraintLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(viewTreeObserver);
        } else {
            constraintLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(viewTreeObserver);
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

*activity_main.xml*:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/id_constraintlayout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textField"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_phone">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="11"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="11"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:minEms="11"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:typeface="monospace" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I enclose an image of the result here below, where I already typed 6 digits:

[image: TextInputEditText lenghted 11 digits]